# Windows batch file to process camera images

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file to take photos off a camera or sd drive (which are specific and don't change.

I then want to move all the *.jpg to a different drive on the company's internal network.

The way it's set up it will look like `n:\jobnumberfolder\pictures.jpg`

I need the files to be able to be renamed like: "vpi(1).jpg", "vpi(2).jpg" and so on (the same thing you accomplish in Windows by highlighting multiple files and clicking rename.

The batch file will prompt the user for a job number (which will be the folder it will be moved to), and a description (what to name the file).

My programming experience is limited and in php and python, but I do understand the very basics: loops, if-else, arrays,... things like that.

My problem is that with the batch file, I cannot seem to find a good way to create a for loop to get what I want. I think I could do this in python using the os module, but I feel like I'm missing something simple (like a simple command or something I could be using for Windows).

I cannot even get a variable to increment, even with delayed expansion command. Even if I could, would it be possible to add it to the file name? I tried to find an answer for this, but have not been able to.

So my question are:

1. Can i actually do this in a batch file?
2. Would it be easier to just write a python script to do it, which will cause me to have to install python on the company's computer? I just want to be able to rename a file with a incrementing number at the end.

Something like this is what I'm looking for

i = 0
name = "whatever"
for each jpg in camera/images
    rename each to whatever + i
    i+=1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What to do if jobnumber exists?

Comment: rename *.jpg while still on the camera or sd card, then move it to jobnumber folder. Moving part is easy. I'm just having trouble renaming the files to something like: picture(1), picture(2), and so on.

Comment: If jobnumber folder exists, and there are files in it, renumbered from a previous run, how should the new files be numbered? And there is no way (more or less) to know if any of the currently files been copied is yet inside jobnumber folder. Duplicated files are acceptable? Or this will not happen?

Comment: I want to rename them before moving. When it reaches its destination in jobnumber folder, there will be no other files of the same name, but there will be many other jpg images. Thats why I want to rename before moving them over...like this.  1. rename cameradrive/images/*.jpg to descriptionName(1), descriptionName(2) for however many jpgs are in the specified camera folder. 2. After renaming them, I want to move them to a specific jobnumber folder, which will not have other files named like these ones. The renaming must take place on the camera drive.

Comment: The renaming can happen during the copy - this will save wear and tear on the SD card in the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `n:\` in two places and `f:\cam-folder\` where needed.  It's untested:

```
@echo off
:loop
cls
echo Enter "jobnumberfolder,description" with comma and no quotes:
echo similar to     986,vpi
set "var="
set /p "var="
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in ("%var%") do set "job=%%a"&set "desc=%%b"
echo "%job%" "%desc%" - correct? press enter to continue or N to start again:
set "var="
set /p "var="
if defined var goto :loop
md "n:\%job%\" 2>nul
setlocal enabledelayedexapansion
echo.
set c=0
for %%a in ("f:\cam-folder\*.jpg") do (
   set /a c+=1
   echo copying "n:\%job%\%desc%(!c!)%%~xa"
   copy "%%a" "n:\%job%\%desc%(!c!)%%~xa" >nul
)
echo done
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem configuration
    set "sourceFolder=w:\images"
    set "targetFolder=n:\jobs"

    rem test if there is something to copy
    if not exist "%sourceFolder%\*.jpg" (
        echo NO FILES FOUND
        goto endProcess
    )

:askJob 
    rem ask job number
    set /p "jobNumber=Job Number  : "

    rem test if no job number
    if "%jobNumber%"=="" (
        echo NO JOB NUMBER - End of process
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem test for existing job number
    if exist "%targetFolder%\%jobNumber%" (
        echo DUPLICATE JOB
        goto askJob
    )

    rem ask for description
    set /p "description=Description : "

    rem test for no description
    if "%description%"=="" (
        echo NO DESCRIPTION - End of process
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem WARNING - No test for valid job number nor valid description
    rem WARNING - Don't shoot your own foot, or add code to validate
    rem WARNING - according to your needs

    rem create target job folder
    set "target=%targetFolder%\%jobnumber%"
    mkdir "%target%" > nul 2>nul

    rem DO THE COPY 
    rem Generate a file list (dir), numerate it (findstr /n) and for each line
    rem in generated list, split the number from the filename (for with delims)
    rem and copy source file to numbered target file

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%f in ('dir /tc /od /b "%sourceFolder%\*.jpg" ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
        echo transfer: "%sourceFolder%\%%g" == "%target%\%description%(%%f).*"
        copy "%sourceFolder%\%%g" "%target%\%description%(%%f).*" >nul 2>nul
    )

    echo FILES COPIED

:endProcess
    rem Clean 
    endlocal

    rem and exit
    exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this tomorrow. What does the "tokens=1, * delims=;" %%f" mean?

Comment: When the list of files is processed with findstr, the number is included as a prefix in the line, and a colon `:` added as separator from content (filename). To split the line, the `for` command is instructed to use `:` as a delimiter to split the line, and from the splitted line, we want two tokens: the first containing text before the first `:`, and the second containing the rest of the line. First token (line number) will be placed in %%f (the indicated variable) and second token (filename) in next variable, %%g